# how to update datagridview after selecting row and changed in text box value and clicking update? which is connected to access db

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, .net-4.8

i want to update the datagridview list after clicking on button update [here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7tOS.png)

when i select raw heading its shows on textboxes and after changing the value and clicking update its showing msg record updated successfully. [here's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP9sp.png).

but its not updating in datagridview..

```
private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            if (ValueTextBox.Text != "" && TypeTextBox.Text != "")
            {

                cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Sflorotype set Sflorovalues=@value,Sflorotypes=@type where ID=@id", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", ValueTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", TypeTextBox.Text);
                var returnValue =
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
                con.Close();
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
            }
        }
        OleDbDataAdapter adapt;
        private void DisplayData()
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Sflorotype", con);
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridViewList.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
        private void ClearData()
        {
            ValueTextBox.Text = "";
            TypeTextBox.Text = "";
            ID = 0;
        }

 private void dataGridViewList_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            ValueTextBox.Text = dataGridViewList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            TypeTextBox.Text = dataGridViewList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: You're doing it completely the wrong way around. You should have a DataTable bound to the grid. When the user makes changes, you update that DataTable first, so the grid updates automatically. You then use a data adapter to save the changes from the DataTable back to the database. You should generally use the same adapter you used to retrieve the data in the first place and you can save multiple changes in a single batch. You can even bind the DataTable to the other controls too so there's no code required to move data around.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't add comment - I am new here.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Sflorotype set Sflorovalues=@value,Sflorotypes=@type where ID=@id", con);
```

Are you sure as ID is 94? (at your image, there is ID 94) Because I don't see where you get this value.

I found ID only here, and you set it to 0:

```
    private void ClearData()
    {
        ValueTextBox.Text = "";
        TypeTextBox.Text = "";
        ID = 0;
    }
```

I see only here some ID value. And if you don't change it elsewhere, it will update ID with value 0.

You can easily get info what you are executing:

```
string command = "update Sflorotype set Sflorovalues=@value,Sflorotypes=@type where ID=@id";
MessageBox.Show(command);
cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, con);
```

EDIT:

try this in your UpdateButton_Click:

```
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "update Sflorotype set Sflorovalues=@value,Sflorotypes=@type where ID=@id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", ValueTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", TypeTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); {
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
                con.Close();
            }
            DisplayData();
            ClearData();
```

Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID) - this should be the last one in adding parameters.

Comment: so what should I do ?